# Why doesn't Delayed Jobs work with my ActionMailer production setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am working on a Ruby (1.8.6) on Rails (2.3.5) application in which I am currently using Gmail to deliver email messages. I want to switch to sending the messages with Delayed Jobs.

I have delayed jobs sending messages on my development environment but when I deploy to my production server and try the messages get rejected and an error shows up in my delayed_jobs table: `530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i25sm12946175anh.17.` I've seen this error before (when I don't have TLS enabled in my config). But it was working before I started using delayed_jobs. Here is my mail config:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'example.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => 'user@example.com',
  :password => 'password'
}
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

**Update**: The application is actually running on REE ruby 1.8.7. So maybe delayed jobs is somehow using the regular ruby interpreter installed on the server (1.8.6). But, how do I get delayed jobs to use my REE install? And how do I tell what things are using what version of Ruby.

Comment: Are you running the delayed_job worker?

Comment: Yeah I am. Its trying to send them, they getting rejected by gmail.

Comment: I set Ruby EE as my default and the emails send with no error. But now I'm getting duplicates. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, how do I get delayed jobs to use
>   my REE install? And how do I tell what
>   things are using what version of Ruby.

The `script/delayed_job` command uses the system Ruby. So "`which ruby`" should point to the REE installation. If not, you can force it by using the Ruby executable. Lets say, your REE is installed at `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01`. Then:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/ruby script/delayed_job -n 2 start
```

Or if you use the rake command to start, like:

```
$ rake jobs:work -t RAILS_ENV=production
```

Then `which rake` should point to your REE installation. If its not, then you can make it use REE by:

```
RAILS_ENV=production /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/rake jobs:work -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use `:enable_starttls_auto` as you wrote, but that only works for ruby >= 1.8.7 and ruby >= 1.9.

So you need to use the solution as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641354/problem-communicating-with-gmail-in-rails-app): define a file `smtp_tls.rb` which you place in your initializers folder.

Comment: yeah, thats what I thought. I just don't get why it works if I don't use delayed jobs to send it.