# 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been getting this error trying to send an email via Net:SMTP on ruby 2.2.6, rails 5.0.1, seen many topics but nothing is really working there, I might be missing something and an external help would be nice ! Here's how I send the mail in a basic controller :

`Net::SMTP.start('smtp.gmail.com') do |smtp| smtp.send_message message,'mail@gmail.com', 'mail@gmail.com'`

and that's my dev.rb conf for mail:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.perform_caching = true

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
enable_starttls_auto: true,
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  domain:               'localhost:3000',
  port:                 587,
  user_name:            'mail@gmail.com',
  password:             'pass',
  authentication:       'plain',
```

}

Comment: can you give this solution a try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641372/2091457

Comment: I could, but the problem is that this solution is for an outdated version of rails and they now implemented the enable_starttls_auto option, so I will look into it if no other solution comes, but I would really like not to use this solution ! Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to drop the database and then create, migrate the database again. After that, you may face another challenge like me right now "Gmail: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at". if not, your email will be sent successfully. Good luck!

Comment: Since the issue was created more than 1 year ago, I wouldn't be able to recreate it and to verify if that works but thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

what about allowing less secure apps to use your email in google configuration? here is the link to enable it:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps